# Google sheets macro won't run on trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created the following script to delete content in a range using a macro.

It works properly when I run the macro.

But it does not work when I set a time based trigger. The trigger log says it ran successfully but the cell contents were not actually deleted

Here is my code:

```
function Clear_Send_Status() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J2:J13').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Comment: Why are you activating a range? There is no UI context in a time based trigger - just clear the content of the `Range` directly (instead of `.activate()`)

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that time-driven triggers can't activate ranges and can't get active rangelist because they are methods that require that an user run the script. Consider that when this script runs, there is no guarantee that the spreadsheet is even open in a browser.

Try

```
function Clear_Send_Status() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('J2:J13');
  range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

This directly operates on the `Range` variable `range` instead of trying to activate it and then operate on the active `RangeList`.