# Google sheets macro only working when I manually trigger it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hubspot

I have a spreadsheet that is connected a Hubspot workflow. When a deal is closed in our CRM, Hubspot creates a new row on the sheet with 3 pieces of data from the deal. Due to Hubspot's recommended best practices for working with Google Sheets integration, I have another sheet where I reference data from the sheet that receives the data. The problem arose when I realized that the reference sheet would not automatically refresh when new data was written to the synced sheet. So, I created a macro that copies the formula down using the fill handle every 5 minutes. This rescans the synced sheet and writes any new data to the reference sheet. This morning I woke up and there was some new data that should have been copied over to the reference sheet -- however it wasn't. I checked that the macro is running every 5 minutes, and it is. For the hell of it, I went to the menu and manually ran the macro and, to my surprise, it actually worked! I want this to be fully automated though and don't want to have to manually run a macro everytime I want the data to get copied over.

Data gets synced here [image]

Data is referenced here [image]

Macro Code:

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function RefreshData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A75').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A75:A223'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B75').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('B75:B234'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C75').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('C75:C232'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C75:C232').activate();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function RefreshData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  sh.getRange('A75').autoFill(sh.getRange('A75:A223'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  sh.getRange('B75').autoFill(sh.getRange('B75:B234'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  sh.getRange('C75').autoFill(sh.getRange('C75:C232'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your macro, doesn't work in the time-driven triggers context. The following "macro" is able to be called by a time-driven trigger:

```
function RefreshDataByTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  spreadsheet.getRange('A75:A223')
    .setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('A75').getValue());  
  spreadsheet.getRange('B75:B234')
    .setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('B75').getValue());
  spreadsheet.getRange('C75:C232')
    .setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('C75').getValue()); 
};
```

Note:

1. `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */` was not included in the above code because it applies to the whole project.
2. I'm intentional using `setValue` instead of `setValues` as the same value should be added to all the cells from the specified range.

---

There are some methods that only works in certain contexts, i.e. `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` works then called from a custom menu, but doesn't work when called from a time-driven trigger. The same happens with `Range.activate()`. Unfortunately the macro recorder adds a lot of `Range.activate()` and `Spreadsheet.getActiveRange()` methods and it's not smart enough yet to optimize the recorded user actions by itself, so, in order to make your macro to work when it's called by a time-driven trigger  you have to adapt your code:

1. Remove statements like `spreadsheet.getRange('A75').activate();`.
2. Modify statements like `spreadsheet.getActiveRange()` to use statements like `spreadsheet.getRange('A75')`.

If you are also interested in making your "macro" faster, you might also would like to replace patterns like

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A75').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A75:A223'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

by equivalent code that make fewer calls to Google Apps Script methods.

Related

- [Google sheets macro won't run on trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53982769/1595451)